# How to create an append method for a char array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, append

I'm currently working on a project for a class to create a TextLine class that represents the a line of text that must be represented as an array of characters.

For one of the methods, I am supposed to take in a string as an argument of a parameter and then append that string to my already created char array.

I was trying to search online for how I could do this, or even an example of the String or StringBuffer class that showed the implementation, but due to my novice skills at Google, I couldn't really find anything useful.

What I 'm thinking is that I first have to convert the string to the array, and then somehow using one of the array methods to add each char individually to the char array.

This is what I have:

```
public void append(String fragment){

    char[] temp = fragment.toCharArray();

}
```

I'm not quite sure what array method could be used, if there even is one. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Is your end-goal appending strings? You can do that with the + operator. The problem with using toCharArray is that the String can contain UTF code-points, which are represented using multiple bytes. Without knowing the encoding, your bytes are pretty useless.

Comment: @thinhtvu: why the heck are you trying to delete the code in the accepted answer (via an attempted edit)? This action frankly stinks. Shame on you and -1. Moderators have been flagged.

Comment: All note that the original poster also tried to delete the code posted in Toader Mihai Claudiu's answer *which he accepted*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would use a `StringBuilder` as the internal storage for your class but i assume that you need the basic details of how to do this.

The basic process is like this:

- allocate a new array with the size of old array + size of the new data
- copy the old data into the new array
- copy the new data at the end of the new array
- set this as the actual data

Here is the code (this assumes that the `data` member is declared like this: `char[] data = new char[0]`:

```
    public void append(String fragment) {
       char[] fragmentChars = fragment.toCharArray();
       char[] newData = new char[data.length + fragmentChars.length];

       System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);
       System.arraycopy(fragmentChars, 0, newData, data.length, fragmentChars.length);

       data = newData;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your original `char[]` array is called `arr`. Then you can do:

```
public void append(String fragment){
    arr = (new String(arr)+fragment).toCharArray();
}
```

This converts your `char[]` array into a `String` so you can simply concatenate that to `fragment` using the `+` operator. Then you simply convert the new `String` back to a `char[]` array using `toCharArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System.arraycopy method to copy the contents of one array into another array.  I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out the details.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can try a slightly more straightforward method:

```
public class Test{
char[] arr;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Test t = new Test();
    t.arr = "hi ".toCharArray();
    t.append(" and bye");
    System.out.print(new String(t.arr));
}

public void append(String myString){
    char[] toAppend = myString.toCharArray();
    char[] newArr = new char[toAppend.length+arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < toAppend.length-1; i++)
        newArr[i+arr.length] = toAppend[i];
    arr = newArr;
}
}
```